# How to have fixed width on window resize?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a body background and I have a div in that body.On window resize, I want to have the application as such. To maintain the width,if I give fixed width to the body,on window resize I am not getting the scroll bar and as a result full page is not displayed. If I dont give fixed width, the page alignment changes and it the elements inside the body gets collapsed on window resize. Here is my code.Thanks in advance.

```
 body.background
{
    background: url(../images/common/header/Background_color.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:top center;  
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background-size:contain; 
    position:fixed;
    overflow:auto;
}

div.emptybody
{
   height:100%;
   width:97%;
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   margin: 0px 25px 25px 25px;
   height:470px;
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-attachment:fixed;
}


<body class="background">
<div class="emptybody">

-------------other elements and contents---------------

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> To maintain the width,if I give fixed width to the body.

You're not using a fixed width in your code, using '%' is dynamic.
On re-sizing your window it will always calculate in '%' from every border of the screen.

You need the page to 'overflow', to exceed the borders of the screen.
There are two ways of doing that:

1. Give your div a fixed width in pixels

   div.emptybody { height: auto; width: 900px;}
2. Give the 'children' divs within their parent (div.emptybody)  a fixed width.

   div.emptybody { height: 100%; width: 97%;}
   div.emptybodyChild {height: auto; width: 900px; }

Comment: Actually I tried giving fixed width to body. At that time, if I resize,only part of the page is getting displayed.

Comment: My application looks like I have a background and in the center I have this emptybody div. Now you can see the background in the top,bottom,left and right of the emptybody div. But if I specify fixed width to emptybody div and if I resize, at that time, I am not able to see the background in the right side. I hope you are getting what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
div {
    position:absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

also you can specify div posicion by providing margin-top/left/, or just using top/left/ values

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, but you applied the overflow wrong. The overflow needs to be for the div with your content, and it needs to be set to scroll, find it here:http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/EWwJA/

You also gave two heights for the div. It applied the 100% height before the other height of 470px.
You can also add divs or spans within the main div to get fixed widths and heights if you need it for your content.

HTML:

```
<body class="background">
<div class="emptybody">

    <span class="fixedText">-------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents----------------------------other elements and contents---------------</span>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 body.background
{
    background: #000;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:top center;  
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background-size:contain; 
    position:fixed;
}

div.emptybody
{
   width:250px;
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   margin: 0px 25px 25px 25px;
   height:200px;
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-attachment:fixed;
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: I dont need the scrollbar separately for the div.

Comment: But it wont show the scrollbar for the body if it's set to width and height 100%.. You can add a div inside the body and set it as fixed background..

Comment: If I include overflow:scroll,even if the content does not exceed the limit, I am getting the scroll panel without the bar.Do you get my point?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/EWwJA/ I need like this. But when I resize the window the right part of background is not visible because it is overlapped by the div if I specify some fixed width for div

Comment: You want it to show the background when you resize the browser? Have you tried margin: 0 auto; for the content div http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/EWwJA/8/ I added a div with 80% and then the content div with 100%.. I applied margin 0 auto to the wrap div but it was aligning to the right more and then I added it to the content div as well and it's centering..